# Json contentType: breaks Jquery POST to MVC controller

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

I'm was trying to fill in a description field when a drop-down was selected. I Got it working but I couldn't use a Json Content Type. This works

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ddl_id").change(function () {
            var test = $("#ddl_id").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<%= Url.Action("GetVal") %>",
                data: {id: test},
                //contentType: "text/plain",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(result) {
                    $("#serial").val(result);
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    alert(e);
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

But when I uncomment the contentType: I get null returned to my controller. I've also tried

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

This is my controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetVal(string id)
    {.......
```

Why is it that when I have a contentType I get null passed? And what is the best way to encode Json data? I'm totally new at this and I couldn't find a straight forward explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<%= Url.Action("GetVal") %>",
      data: JSON.stringify({id: test}),
      contentType: "application/json",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(result) {
          $("#serial").val(result);
      },
      error: function(e) {
          alert(e);
      }
});
```

One of the gotchas with this function is that specifying a JSON contentType does not actually cause jQuery to JSON-encode your request.  You have to do so manually or it will be serialized to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

You need [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) and/or native JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the response but, I tired what you gave me and I still can't get Null in the controller. The post has {"ID":"string"} but it still shows null on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

On the server side, use an object to get the parameters value.
like :

```
public class sealed MyClass{
   public Int32 ID{get;set;}
   // other properties here...
}
```

in the action method use like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyClass mycls){
    // here your can get the property,like
    mycls.ID;
}
```

you can read read the MSDN blog:
[Introducing ASP.NET MVC 3 (Preview 1)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/27/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx)